# Cannot import com.google.android.wearable.intent.RemoteIntent for Wear OS app

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

I'm trying to implement an 'Open on phone' button on a Wear OS app, but am unable to import the `RemoteIntent` class.

When I add import `com.google.android.wearable.intent.RemoteIntent` to my `MainActivity.java` the wearable is underlined in red with a 'Cannot resolve symbol' error.

Do I need to add a particular dependency to my project for this to be available?

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/wearable/intent/RemoteIntent) for `RemoteIntent` don't give me any clues as to what I might be missing.

For context, I am trying to use the following snippet in my app:

```
private void openOnPhone(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(this, intent, null);
    // 'Open on phone' confirmation overlay
    new ConfirmationOverlay().setType(ConfirmationOverlay.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION).setMessage("Opened on phone").showOn(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import:

`androidx.wear:wear-remote-interactions:1.0.0`

Then instead use something like:

```
RemoteActivityHelper(application).startRemoteActivity(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
               .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                data = Uri.parse("some://uri")
            },
            null
        )
```

However, this library does require compileSdkVersion 31 (Android 12)

Comment: Is it possible to download a file using DownloadManager?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one or both of the following dependencies:

```
androidx.wear:wear-phone-interactions:1.0.0-beta01
androidx.wear:wear-remote-interactions:1.0.0-beta01
```

It's mentioned in the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/wear#wear_ongoing_interactions_version_100_2). There's also a note about renaming it that might be relevant to you:

> We have added the RemoteIntentHelper class (previously RemoteIntent in
> the Wearable Support Library) which can be used for opening intents on
> other devices (i.e. from watch to phone). (I1d7e0)

Comment: Nope, afraid not.. adding both dependencies makes no difference at all.. the import still shows an error.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I'm able to access RemoteActivityHelper (that used to be called RemoteIntentHelper) when I add the two dependencies above to my project. Maybe you're not supposed to import com.google.android.wearable.intent.RemoteIntent directly?

Comment: I've added the code snippet that I am trying to integrate into my app to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This package:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1'
```

Comment: This is deprecated. Use androidx.wear.* namespace for further development for coming Wear OS 3. Support-Libraries are only for Wear OS <2.